# Passing Data through in a rawQuery Dart

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I am getting an error message saying that genre_id is null when I pass an id (integer data) through pages. So there is something wrong when I use the index as a variable to pass on an id to the next page. How do I use index to pass it as an id for the next page?

In my sqlite database that I am using, I have a tbl_genres and a tbl_books with the book entries being tied to the genre table with a genre_id (a column in both tables).

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: !loading ? new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: genreList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("${genreList[index]}"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            BookListPage(id: index), //how to pass index as an int?
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            );
          },
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
```

Here is my next page...

```
class BookListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int id;
  BookListPage({this.id});
  @override
  _BookListPageState createState() => _BookListPageState();
}

class _BookListPageState extends State<BookListPage> {
  bool loading;
  List<Map> bookNames;

  final int id;
  _BookListPageState({this.id});
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    getBookData();

  }

  Future getBookData() async {
    print(id);
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "asset_sample_sqlite.db");
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "sample_sqlite.db"));
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    Database db = await openDatabase(path);
    final _bookList = await db.rawQuery('SELECT book_name[] FROM tbl_books WHERE genre_id = $id'); //how to reference the passed id?
    await db.close();

    setState((){
      loading = false;
      bookNames = _bookList;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: !loading ? new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: bookNames.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text("${bookNames[index]}"),
              ),
            );
          }
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

And also how do I use that index in the rawQuery to display information only relating to that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your second page as follows:

```
class BookListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  BookListPage({this.id});
  @override
  _BookListPageState createState() => _BookListPageState();
}

class _BookListPageState extends State<BookListPage> {
  bool loading;
  List<Map> bookNames;

  _BookListPageState();
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    getBookData();

  }

  Future getBookData() async {
    print(widget.id);
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me solve my problem of displaying the right information according to which genre. However I am still having trouble in the first page passing the index in the ListView as an id parameter for the next. (in materialpageroute) How would I do that?

Comment: What's not working? Compile error? Runtime exception? Does `WHERE genre_id = ${widget.id}` work?